# Add default Scripts folder and missing files in Content folder in empty ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, scripting, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an empty ASP.NET Web application project (MVC 5). In the layout it references bootstrap and jquery files:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I do not have a scripts folder and my content folder only contains Site.css. How can I include the default Scripts folder and other files in the Content folder as I would see when I create a project with the MVC template?

Comment: Cant use just right click on the solution and add a new folder called Scripts?

Comment: it would be an empty folder.  I need all the default files that come in it such as jquery-3.4.1.min.js and bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: i have added an empty scripts folder and empty content folder. i installed bootstrap from nuget package manager and it seems to have added the files into the folders but when i run the page its still not showing the bootstrap